# AVRO Tool 1.8.2 - Gives error Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid sync! at line 245

Tags: java, apache, avro, avro-tools

I have a requirement to combine avro files and push it Azure blob store.
I combined it and then i try to read it again i get error.

I have a file in which avro files are combined using snappy. While running the following command:

```
java -jar .\avro-tools-1.8.2.jar tojson inputfile
```

I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Invalid sync!
```

I debugged the code and the line below where the syncBufferis compared with header.sync is giving problem. Any ideas what might be the issue.

```
DataFileStream.DataBlock nextRawBlock(DataFileStream.DataBlock reuse) throws IOException {
    if (!this.hasNextBlock()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else {
        if (reuse != null && reuse.data.length >= (int)this.blockSize) {
            reuse.numEntries = this.blockRemaining;
            reuse.blockSize = (int)this.blockSize;
        } else {
            reuse = new DataFileStream.DataBlock(this.blockRemaining, (int)this.blockSize);
        }

        this.vin.readFixed(reuse.data, 0, reuse.blockSize);
        this.vin.readFixed(this.syncBuffer);
        this.availableBlock = false;
        if (!Arrays.equals(this.syncBuffer, this.header.sync)) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid sync!");
        } else {
            return reuse;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of showing one line of code?

Comment: This is code from the library , i was debugging into the library. trying to identify what is breaking.

Comment: public class DataFileWriter<D> implements Closeable, Flushable  --- what is the use of sync interval ? is there any chance if my file content are small this will not write the sync marker ?